# Theme inheritance with magento

Tags: magento

I am working on a magento website. I have 4 categories, and two of them use an other theme (no my specific magento theme) . How can i configure my theme to get missing files from my default theme instead of the base theme.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Normally it would be best to create a new theme package and template for your design, and then move any `base/default` changes into `your_package/default` and use it as a 2nd tier fall back to your designs.

- http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magentos-theme-hierarchy/